# Removing Strings from Arrays using a submethod JAVA

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I need to use the method "remove" that accepts an ArrayList of Strings and a target String as two parameters, and searches and deletes all matched Strings from the ArrayList. For example, calling remove on the ArrayList [“Go”, “Go”, “Go”] and the target String “Go”, would result in an empty ArrayList.

```
public class Remove {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>();  
        x.add("Go");
        x.add("Go");
        x.add("Go");
        System.out.println(x);
        remove("Go");
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void remove(String t) {
        ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
            if(x.get(i).equals(t)) {
                x.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: *that accepts an ArrayList of Strings and a target String as two parameters*: does your remove method respect these requirements? I only see one parameter.

Comment: `x` is empty. Did you mean to pass the `x` from the `main` method as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove` method creates a new `ArrayList` and then attempts to remove a value from it. Instead, you should pass a list to the method. Additionally, using JDK 8's [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method would make your code much simpler:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<>();  
    x.add("Go");
    x.add("Go");
    x.add("Go");
    System.out.println(x);
    remove(x, "Go");
    System.out.println(x);
}

public static void remove(List<String> list, String t) {
    list.removeIf(s -> s.equals(t));
}
```